# Is my thinking right for the simple harmonic circuit

Tags: impedance, harmonics

If this is a simple harmonic circuit, then what is the \$X_C\$?

[image]

I know harmonic circuit means that there is no value in the imaginary part of the impendence or admittance, that is, \$Z_{th}=R+0j\$ or \$Y_{th}=G+0j\$.

In this question, if the circuit wants to be a harmonic circuit, I think \$\frac{1}{R_1+12j}=Y_1\$, and \$\frac{1}{-jX_C}=Y_2=\$, and \$Y_1+Y_2=\$real value, not complex value.

So \$Y_1+Y_2=\frac{1}{1+12j}+\frac{1}{-jX_C}=\frac{1-12j}{145}+\frac{j}{X_C}=\frac{(1-12j)X_C+145j}{145X_C},\$ so now our purpose is let \$-12X_Cj+145j=0\$,

that is \$12X_C=145\$,so \$X_C \approx 12Ω\$

The solution from the book

\$X_C=X_Lp=\frac{1^2+12^2}{12}=12Ω\$

Although our answer are the same, I still want to ask that is my thinking, right? Why can the book just calculate like that, it seems the author just use some unknown formula. Does anyone know about that formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drill down through the equation for the impedance of the circuit and equate the imaginary terms to zero you find that the frequency where the phase angle is purely resistive is: -

$$\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC} -\dfrac{R^2}{L^2}}$$

Then, if you square both sides and merge \$\omega\$ with the L and C terms to produce impedance terms you get: -

$$1 = \dfrac{X_C}{X_L} - \dfrac{R^2}{X_L^2}$$

$$\dfrac{X_C}{X_L} = 1 + \dfrac{R^2}{X_L^2}$$

$$X_C = X_L + \dfrac{R^2}{X_L}$$

So,

$$X_C = 12 + \dfrac{1^2}{12^2} = 12.0833\text{ ohms}$$

Comment: thanks,so my thinking of calculation is right?/

Comment: @shineele yes, your derivation is correct. I just showed a different way to get to the same answer and that basically double checks things. Xc cannot be exactly 12.000 though.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!